# VBS - how to pass object to function as parameter

Tags: object, vbscript

I am working on little script and made wrong decision to do it in VBS.

```
...
result = FindAndUpdate(objDictionary, id)
...
Function FindAndUpdate(objDictionary, id)
    MsgBox(objDictionary.Count)
    FindAndUpdate = true
End Function
```

Now I am struggling with things that doesn't make any sense.  I am passing Dictionary object to function. In function MsgBox(objDictionary.count) executes and I get number 15 in alert box, but immediately error gets reported on the same line **Object Required: 'objDictionary'**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: uh... well. My fault. Since all of the code were in loop. There was situation when objDictionary would equal Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add a check for the objDictionary and exit your function if it doesn't exist:

```
Function FindAndUpdate(objDictionary, id)
  If Not IsObject(objDictionary) Then
    FindAndUpdate = false
    Exit Function
  End If

  MsgBox(objDictionary.Count)
  FindAndUpdate = true
End Function
```